# How to load csv couple of lines per couple of lines

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, bigdata, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm connecting Spark to Cassandra and I was able to print the lines of my CSV using the conventional COPY method. However, if the CSV was very large as it usually happens in Big Data, how could one load the CSV file couple of lines per couple of lines in order to avoid freezing related issues etc. ?

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import com.datastax.spark.connector._

object SparkCassandra {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

      val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkCassandra").setMaster("local").set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "localhost")
      val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
      val my_rdd = sc.cassandraTable("my_keyspace", "my_csv")
      my_rdd.take(20).foreach(println)
      sc.stop()
  }
}
```

Should one use a time variable or something of that nature?

Comment: you mean loading file into Cassandra, or from Cassandra?

Comment: Loading the file into Cassandra. I used the copy method and specified the path of the file.

Comment: see the answer - DSBulk could be the simplest thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want just to load data into Cassandra, or unload data from Cassandra using the command-line, I would recommend to look to the [DataStax Bulk Loader (DSBulk)](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/index.html) - it's heavily optimized for loading data to/from Cassandra/DSE. It works with both open source Cassandra and DSE.

In simplest case loading into & unloading from table will look as (default format is CSV):

```sh
dsbulk load -k keyspace -t table -url my_file.csv
dsbulk unload -k keyspace -t table -url my_file.csv
```

For more complex cases you may need to provide more options. You can find more information in [following series of the blog posts](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/03/datastax-bulk-loader-introduction-and-loading).

If you want to do this with Spark, then I recommend to use Dataframe API instead of RDDs.  In this case you'll just use standard `read` & `write` functions.

to export data from Cassandra to CSV:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra._
val data = spark.read.cassandraFormat("tbl", "ks").load()
data.write.format("csv").save("my_file.csv")
```

or read from CSV and store in Cassandra:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode
val data = spark.read.format("csv").save("my_file.csv")
data.cassandraFormat("tbl", "ks").mode(SaveMode.Append).save()
```